# Fundamental theorem of algebra using Cauchy's theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Prove that a polynomial in $z$ without zeros is constant using Cauchy theorem.

> Hint : If $P(z)$ is a polynomial that is not a constant, write $P(z)=P(0)+zQ(z)$, divide by $zP(z)$, and integrate around a large circle. This will lead to a contradiction if $P(z)$ has no zeros.

Consider $$\frac{P(z)}{zP(z)}=\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}+\frac{zQ(z)}{zP(z)}$$

Integrating over circle of radius $R$

$$\int_R\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_R\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}dz+\int_R\frac{Q(z)}{P(z)}dz$$

Assuming $P(z)$ has no zeros, we see that $\int_R\frac{Q(z)}{P(z)}dz=0$ using Cauchy theorem as $\frac{Q(z)}{P(z)}$ is analytic.

See that $\int_R\frac{1}{z}dz=2\pi i$ by considering parametrization $z(\theta)=Re^{i\theta}$.

I do not know how to compute $\int_R\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}dz$ from basics but i can use Residue theorem here and assuming $P(z)$ has no zeros we see that $$\int_R\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}dz=2\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(0)}{P(z)}=2\pi i$$

So, $$2\pi i=\int_R\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_R\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}dz+\int_R\frac{Q(z)}{P(z)}dz=2\pi i$$

I do not see any contradiction.. What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: it seems to work because from $\int_R  \frac{dz}{z} = \int_R  \frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}dz$ you get $$0 = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_R \frac{Q(z)}{P(0)+zQ(z)} dz = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_R \frac{dz}{P(0)/Q(z)+z} dz = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_R \frac{dz}{\mathcal{O}(|R|^{-1})+z}  = ?$$

Comment: Do not use the Residue theorem. Bound the size of that integral using the fact that $P(z) \to \infty$ as $z \to \infty$.

Comment: @user1952009 : I do not understand your argument :O

Comment: @MikeMiller : your method is the same as mine ?

Comment: @user1952009: Looks that way. (I wrote my comment without seeing yours.)

Comment: @MikeMiller: Are you saying with residue theorem i am getting wrong integral? I see that bound goes to zero as $R\rightarrow \infty$ what is wrong with my residue argument

Comment: Of course you're getting the wrong integral. You assumed, falsely, that P has no zeroes.

Comment: @cello, read what I wrote...

Comment: I still do not get the point.. $2\pi i=\int_R\frac{1}{z}dz$ is correct? $\int_R \frac{Q(z)}{P(z)}=0$ is correct? Only $\int_R\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}$ has some ambiguity.. From residue theorem i am getting integral is $2\pi i$ and from bound i am getting $0$.. @MikeMiller

Comment: Yes! It's a contradiction! That's the whole point!

Comment: @user1952009 : I read it.. cOuld not understand what you are trying to do..

Comment: work on it more, open your mind :D

Comment: Ok... So, conclusion is, if i can use residue theorem there is no contradiction... I am using residue theorem assuming $P(z)$ has no zeros... So, assuming that there are no zeros is not giving me contradiction... :O I feel ashamed and funny at this point as i am missing something simple which i can not figure out... @MikeMiller

Comment: @user1952009 : I do not know. some thing is wrong with me at this point of time and could not appreciate your idea... Will come back to your comment once i am ready.. Thanks

Comment: there is no contradiction if you use that $P(z)$ has no zero  for $\int_R \frac{P(0)}{z P(z)}dz$ AND for $\int_R \frac{Q(z)}{ P(z)}dz$, but if  you use that $P(z)$ has no zero  only for one of them, and evaluate the other when $R \to \infty$ only from the fact that $P(z)$ is non-constant, you get a contradiction

Comment: which makes sense : it is impossible that $P(z)$ has no zero AND is non-constant, hence if you use the TWO incompatible properties, you get a contradiction

Comment: I got it now @user1952009

Comment: I got it now @MikeMiller

Answer (score 2):

Starting from $$\int_R\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_R\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}dz+\int_R\frac{Q(z)}{P(z)}dz$$

and using your facts that the LHS = $2 \pi i$ and $\int_R\frac{Q(z)}{P(z)}dz=0$ we have

$$2 \pi i=\int_R\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}dz$$

we can get a contradiction by showing that the RHS $\to 0$ using the ML inequality, as suggested in comments.

$$\left|\int_R\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}dz\right| \le 2 \pi R \cdot \frac{|P(0)|}{|R||P(R)|} = 2 \pi \frac{|P(0)|}{|P(R)|}$$

and clearly this tends to zero unless $|P(R)| = |P(0)|$, so we have a contradiction unless the polynomial is constant.